# How to define persistent matrix variable inside the Scilab function?

Tags: scilab, xcos

I have been developing a Scilab function where I need to have persistent variable of the matrix type. Based on my [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72011161/equivalent-of-static-local-variables-inside-scilab-function) question I have chosen the same approach. Below is the code I have used for test of this approach.

```
function [u] = FuncXYZ(x)

global A;
global init;

if init == 0 then
   init = 1;
   A = eye(4, 4);
endif

u = A(1, 1);

endfunction
```

As soon as I have integrated the function inside my *Xcos* simulation I have been surprised that I see "0" at the output of the *scifunc_block_m*.

Nevertheless I have found that in case I use below given command for "return" from the function

```
u = A(3, 3);
```

the function returns really the expected "1". Additionaly if I take a look at the *Variable Browser* on the top right corner of the Scilab window I can't se the expected `A 4x4` item. It seems that I am doing something wrong.

Can anybody give me an advice how to define a persistent variable of the matrix type inside the Scilab function?
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Please do not spam irrelevant tags. This doesn't have to do with neither MATLAB nor SimuLink.

Comment: I don’t know scilab, in MATLAB you’d use `persistent`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global variables are by default initialized with an empty matrix. Hence, you should detect first call with `isempty()`

```
function [u] = FuncXYZ(x)
  global A;
  global init;
  if isempty(init)
    init = 1;
    A = eye(4, 4);
  end
  u = A(1, 1);
endfunction
```

BTW, your code is incorrect, there is no `endif` in Scilab.